# What trigger the Program Compatibility Assistant when running program

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Even the most simple hello world dialog can cause it.
(the code is from Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition)
After the exe closed, the PCA pop out, and it will no longer pop out again. But if I change the filename of the exe, it will pop out again.

So I am very curious which make theh PCA act, and how to avoid it act anymore. In an another word, I don't want my program trigger the PCA when first running in the other computer.

Comment: From [Excluding Programs from the Program Compatibility Assistant (PCA)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2545347/excluding-programs-from-the-program-compatibility-assistant-pca): "*the best option to exclude a program from PCA is to include, with the program, an application manifest with run level (either Administrator or as limited users) marking for UAC.*".